# A word to describe a value passes the particular threshold

Tags: word-choice

I couldn't even formulate a correct title for this question. I'm having a problem with a word/verb choice to describe some values that "pass(?)" A certain threshold. For example consider

1 3 |5| 7 8

The threshold is 5, but what I got is 3, which couldn't pass the 5.

How would I say it?

That value 3 cannot pass/get over/bypass/pass through the 5.

The word 'pass' sounds natural to my ears but I know there are some alternatives. Or is it rather plainly 'pass'?

Comment: The value does not ***reach*** the threshold (assuming that it's not necessary to go *beyond* the threshold to "pass" whatever test is being conducted).

Comment: How about "The value 3 did not *exceed* the value 5"? I assume these are numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *meets or exceeds* is a very common one. If 5 is the minimum acceptable value, and you refer to 5 as the threshold, you can say "Only values that *meet or exceed* the threshold are acceptable."

Comment: Bless you for sharing, I'll go for *exceed*.